# upload jupiter notebook to html to leave the interactivity of tables aggrid

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

help me figure it out. You need to load jupiter notebook in html to leave the interactivity of ipyaggrid tables.
Try: `jupyter nbconvert --to html_toc --show-input  backtest.ipynb --output output.html`. result:
[image]

Comment: perhaps there are tables that support interactivity when exporting to html, since the output of df, which contains for example more than 100 lines, does not look very good, but you need to view and analyze all the data? can someone tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision: `jupyter nbconvert --execute --ExecutePreprocessor.allow_errors=True --ExecutePreprocessor.store_widget_state=True --to html_toc --show-input  {file}.ipynb --output {output}.html`

via jupiter notebook: see [decision](https://community.plotly.com/t/export-figurewidgets-from-jupyter-notebook-to-html/15556/2)

Comment: here's an example, I'm converting to html